# How to correctly use implode php

Tags: php, csv, implode

So I have this code:

```
$datas .= '"' . implode('", "', $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$body["offset"].",".$body["name"].",".$email . ",".$body["tel"].",".$body["fax"].",".$body["address"].",".$body["address_coordinate"].",".$body["url"].",".$body["image_url"].",".$body["flexible_1"].",".$body["flexible_2"].",".$body["flexible_3"].",".$body["flexible_4"].",".$body["flexible_5"].",".$body["flexible_6"].",".$body["flexible_7"].",".$body["flexible_8"].",".$body["flexible_9"].",".$body["flexible_10"].",".$body["sequence"].",".$body["del_flg"].",".$body["create_date"].",".$body["create_user"].",".$body["update_date"].",".$body["update_user"]).'"'."\r\n";
```

I want it to look like this:

```
"KN01001","01","4","500","Starbuck's","admin@starbucks.com","09-232-821","09-232-822","Upper G/F SM, Juan Luna Extension"
```

Problem is address has comma, so this would separate it.

I really could not construct it right. Please help

this code is from a CSV convert function. In the CSV file each column is separated by a comma.

But my problem is that I have several columns that contains also comma. I would like that those commas in the columns remain as it is.

Comment: Post a sample of your CSV and how you want it to be produced.

Comment: `implode(',', $body);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rolling your own CSV encoding function it might be better to use the built in fputcsv().

```
$out = fopen("php://memory", "w");

foreach($something as $body) {
    fputcsv($out, $body);
}

rewind($out);

$data = stream_get_contents($out);
```

You'll need to adapt the code to order the columns if you want but that's the basic method (Don't forget to close $out either).

To save holding the entire CSV in memory (if this was a file download/export mechanism) you could open php://output instead and write/flush directly to the web-server/browser.

To answer your question directly implode() takes an array as a second argument but you've given it a string so change it to this (and add all the fields):

```
$datas .= '"' . implode('", "', [$body["id"],  $body["prefecture_id"], $body["industry_id"], $body["offset"], ...]) . "\"\r\n";
```

Comment: would this also solve the issue when data has over millions of records it would time-out?

Comment: It would potentially solve php consuming a lot of memory. As for the timeout it depends where it's occurring and what your web server stack is and all the various configured timeout values in both PHP and the web server.

Answer (score 0):

can you use fgetcsv() instead of implode? This would handle the

```
$fileHandle = fopen("filename.csv", "r");
while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  var_dump($row);
  //$row is an array of all the columns in the csv regardless of commas in the dat
}
```

Otherwise if you must use implode, is the data that has a comma enclosed in speech marks: "some date, with a comma". If so you could use a regex to ignore the commas within the speechmarks.  I can't see your data so its hard to say.